# Java code to press ( Shift +page down) keys at a time

Tags: java

I am trying to run a process which generates a log file in unix path.
I have to take screenshot of this unix log file. The unix log file has multiple pages. Could someone help me . i need java code which will open the unix file, and takes the screen shot of each page.

What i did is :
- I opened the unix file and passed "cat  | less
- **after this code has to press pagedown key till it identify the end of file ( in my unix lof file it shows "END" when it reaches end of file)** and  takes screenshot.

code is written for openeing the unix file, passing the command and taking screennshot. For the bolded text i need the code.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Is this an assignment where this is the requirement?  There seems no reason to use screenshots for obtaining text from a file.  And why have you tagged `java`?  Do you need it to be in `java`?

Comment: Yes, need this in java.